# Looping with ARIMA to predict volatility

Tags: stata, arima

A small question about loops in Stata:

I have a dataset that includes the following variables: implied volatility (of stock options), and the delta of that option (elasticity of the option price on the underlying). Delta is between 20 and 80 strictly, with increments of 5. Implied volatility is usually a couple percent.

I want to get this:

```
quietly arima impl_volatility if delta == 20, ar(1) ma(1)
predict tildevol20 if delta == 20
```

looped for each value of `delta` (20, 25, 30, 35, ..., 80), so that the next in the loop would be:

```
quietly arima impl_volatility if delta == 25, ar(1) ma(1)
predict tildevol25 if delta == 25
```

The variable tildevol(delta) should start at `tildevol20` and increase with the delta as well up to `tildevol80`.

I've tried this, and a couple of other iterations, but I can't seem to get it working (`deltalvl` is the name of the local stored values of delta, 20-80).

```
levelsof delta, local(deltalvl)
foreach 1 of local deltalvl {
   quietly arima impl_volatility if delta == `deltalvl', ar(1) ma(1)
   predict tildevol`deltalvl' if delta == `deltalvl'
}
```

It returns nothing, it just runs, then ends, it doesn't give an error.

Stata documentation doesn't seem to have anything on this (or I might just be looking in the wrong place).

Examples of the dataset:

[image: example 1]

[image: example 2]

So every date has every delta between 20-80 with increments of 5, and every delta has an implied volatility. So 1 date > 13 deltas > each delta 1 volatility.

Comment: Nothing reproducible here: no data example we can use. What went wrong? Did you get a syntax error? Results that were not what you expect? No results?  The problem report is just "I can't seem to get it working". Please study the Stata tag wiki for detailed advice.

Comment: That's the weird part, i get no error. 


. do "C:\Users\u1265418\AppData\Local\Temp\STD00000000.tmp"
. foreach 1 of local deltalvl{
  2.         quietly arima impl_volatility if delta == local deltalvl, ar(1) ma(1)
  3.         predict vol`' if delta == local deltalvl
  4. }

. 
end of do-file


It just doesn't seem to run.

Comment: I'll add some data example

Comment: The stated syntax makes no sense to me. You never refer to local macro `1` inside the loop. That is not fatal, yet not what you need. But as `deltalvl` contains, or should contain, a list of values, the `arima` call should fail as illegal.

Comment: I've added some data as an example.

Comment: The Stata tag wiki doesn't advise screenshots. I see dates that are irregularly spaced. `arima` won't work on a time series that is mostly gaps. What does `tsset` tell you?

Comment: All the dates are there, they are just not sorted. Should I sort them before i run ARIMA? I get inconsistent (but close) results.

Comment: I worry on your behalf that your dates are messed up. What you show doesn't rule out integers such as 20171231 and 20080101. `sort`ing here is irrelevant as `arima` won't run without a `tsset` which sorts as a side-effect. Again, you haven't given a data example in the form we ask for or (specifically) answered the query: what does `tsset` tell you?

Comment: The ARIMA runs because we did tsset and tsset goes from 1-245 (number of days) for each delta. So |Jan 1|delta 20|t=1|, |Jan 2|delta 20|t=2| etc, &  |Jan 1|delta 25|t=1|, |Jan 2|delta 25|t=2| etc. It does this for each delta. At least, that should be what it does. However, I looked at the dataset and it does look like it didn't sort correctly by date, rather they are all scrambled. Will take a look at this now.

Comment: Please provide example data using the `dataex` command and not screenshots.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What makes a little more sense would be something like

```
foreach 1 of local deltalvl {
   arima impl_volatility if delta == `1', ar(1) ma(1)
   predict tildevol`1' if delta == `1'
}
```

but it's not easy to predict whether that will work.

`quietly` when debugging is a bad idea. You may need the information Stata will give.